# What are the differences between the three editions of the book "The Structure of Compact Groups"?

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, topological-groups, book-recommendation

meta pre-clarification: I looked into another question like this but the guy didn't mark any specific tags for this type of question.

Here's a link to the amazon book: [http://www.amazon.com/Structure-Compact-Gruyter-Studies-Mathematics/dp/3110296551/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1424802084&sr=8-1&keywords=structure+of+compact+groups](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3110296551)

I bought an ancient version of the book "The Structure of Compact Groups, by Karl H. Hofmann, Sidney A. Morris" (1st edition) which has roughly 750 pages. But the second edition says "revised and augmented edition" and has roughly 830 pages. Then, a few weeks back I decided to check amazon for the second edition and found yet a third which has roughly 920 pages.

Does anyone know what is the specific content that features in the $n$-th book and doesn't feature in the ($n - 1$)-th book?

meta post-question: Can we create a tag for questions of this kind: about the general form of a specific book?